# Scrapy installation issue: ImportError: No module named encodings

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, scrapy

I'm having some issues installing scrapy on my raspberry pi (running wheezy). I have python 2.7.9 installed and I tried to install scrapy via "pip install scrapy" but it gave me this error:

```
pi@custodis:~ $ sudo pip install scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 34, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/calendar.py", line 10, in <module>
    import locale as _locale
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

Do I need to reinstall python? Any advice you could offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: yeah looks like your python is not complete, you really need to install `scrapy` as sudo? maybe it would be better to use `virtualenv` for only using it on the project you need.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by removing all python packages from my system and then reinstalling python 2.7.9. Also for anyone who runs across an issue with "pip install scrapy" freezing up while installing the lxml dependency, install lxml manually using "apt-get install python-lxml"